# MySQL Windows service won't start

Tags: asp.net, mysql, windows

Our server is hosting a mix of asp and php websites. (windows server)

For months mySQL has been working unhindered and suddenly this has now stopped working.

I've tried connecting to MySql using the correct credentials which results in:

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)`

I've tried restarting the service using net stop MySql and net start MySql to no avail.

I have also tried using `telnet localhost 3306` and `telnet 127.0.0.1` and can confirm that the port is not acessible.

My hosting provider has inspected the step but is at a loss as to how we can remedy the situation.  They have also inspected firewall settings and all seems to be correct.

Comment: Is there anything in the event log? You should see a service start failure, and hopefully some more diagnostics. You can probably also try running the server not as a service to see if that gives you more information but off the top of my head I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Actually I may have been a bit hasty with the title change. Is the service definitely running? Can you see it on `netstat -ano`? Is anything else bound to port 3306?

Answer (score 0):

find physical database files on disk.
back them up.
restard host computer.
then follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit.exe, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

1. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
2. Type MaxUserPort and then press ENTER.
3. Double-click the MaxUserPort value, and then type the maximum value in decimal or hexadecimal.

You must type a number in the range of 500065534 (decimal). Setting this parameter to a value outside of the valid range causes the nearest valid value to be used (5000 or 65534).

1. Click OK.
2. Quit Registry Editor.

restart host computer again. you should be fine now.

The issue is caused because IIS is complete garbage, and keeps consuming ports to connect to MySQL using ODBC. there is no max port value, so when all prots are used up, application crashes. You can solve this issue by following the stebs above, or by reviewing your asp.net application to use mysql connnect / net, instead of ODBC.

Comment: How would that help? That looks like you're trying to prevent something else binding to the port (and there's a better way to do that, but I forget) but if something else was bound to the port wouldn't he be able to connect to it, just not get MySQL?

Comment: Thank you for your replies and sorry for the delay in my reply but I bit the bullet before I saw your post and restarted the server and everything was working again.  Still haven't found a reason though as this server has been serving pages for a year without error.

Comment: as i mentioned earlier, this is due to the limited number of requests you have received through out the year. generally IIS is not encouraged for hosting, as well. anw, good luck.